# NSAttributedString: heading on non-paragraphs

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring, textkit

I'm building a dictionary with a big `UITextView` with multiple `NSAttributedString` for each word. I'm trying to set a fixed space before lines like below but I can't set heading on the text starting by "L'ensemble" as it's not a paragraph (not starting with \n ).

Do you have an idea on to achieve this?

[image]

Here is my code so far which doesn't work as `valueParaStyle` doesn't do anything because `valueText`doesn't start with \n.

Thanks.

```
let senseNumberParaStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
senseNumberParaStyle.paragraphSpacingBefore = 20

let valueParaStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
valueParaStyle.firstLineHeadIndent = 20
valueParaStyle.headIndent = 20

for i in 0..<senses.count {
    let senseNumberText = NSAttributedString(string: "\n\(i + 1).", attributes: [
        NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Bold", size: 14)!,
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor(red: 1, green: 0.275, blue: 0.294, alpha: 1),
        NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: senseNumberParaStyle
    ])

    wordText.appendAttributedString(senseNumberText)

    if let value = senses[i].value {
        let valueText = NSAttributedString(string: " \(value)", attributes: [
            NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Regular", size: 15)!,
            NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor(red: 0.2, green: 0.2, blue: 0.2, alpha: 1),
            NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: valueParaStyle
        ])

        wordText.appendAttributedString(valueText)
    }
}
```

Comment: "I can't set heading on the text starting by "L'ensemble" as it's not a paragraph" -- what do you mean by that?

Comment: Well I want all lines to have the same heading but with a offset between the number and the beginning of the definition.

Comment: Oh, by "heading" you mean "headIndent"? I'd recommend posting an image of your current results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are on the right track. You just need to add a `"\t"` at your first line:

```
 var paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
 paragraphStyle.headIndent = 20

 label.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: "1.\tHere comes your text. Indent as you really want it", attributes:[NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : paragraphStyle])
```

Without the `"\t"`:

[image]

With `"\t"`:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer but since the number at the beginning of the paragraph has a different style than the definition, heading doesn't work on lines after the first one, but it's almost good though.
Is there a way to make two attributed strings a single paragraph?